# Shapes in CSS or HTML

Tags: html, css

I have been wondering why there are no special shape tags in HTML or styles in CSS to make the shapes, like triangles, circles or polygons etc. I don't understand why something of such nature has not been implemented. Is it that they have not thought of it? which I really doubt, or they have on purpose refused to make it available?.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 2):

This is principally because the box model concept requires that block-level elements are rectangular. The reason for this is to allow predictable behaviour with regards to how these elements react to each other when, say, stacked on top of or floated next to one another.

(Sidenote: This suited the early internet perfectly because sites were based on verticality and had little in the way of visually-defined containers - it was one block of text after another, perhaps broken by a picture. Stacking things horizontally didn't really come into it until later.)

As @Cristy's link in the comments shows, there are tricks to creating more complex shapes. Circles and ovals, for example, can be achieved via creative use of `border-radius`. Other shapes rely on distortion via the `transform` property.

However it's important to remember that such simulated shapes will nonetheless be considered by the browser to have a bounding BOX. This is the underpinning principle that will govern how close one element is to another, and how their edges meet.

Answer (score 2):

Neither HTML nor CSS are drawing programs. While such objects can be created, they are convoluted hacks, at least to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

Html5

```
     <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
     style="border:1px solid #000000;">
     </canvas>
```

can be used to draw shapes.

Comment: Actually, it's javascript that does the drawing. canvas is only the, uh, canvas.

Comment: There is value in the OP realising that canvas provides the possibility of more complex shapes on a webpage. However those shapes are of course not HTML elements, but bitmaps that are untargetable (as elements) and exist only in visual memory once committed to the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 and CSS3 can achieve this, to see all possible shapes that can be created, a cheat sheet has been made at http://www.land-of-web.com/freebies/css3-simple-shapes-cheat-sheet.html

EDIT: Utkanos is right, you can create shapes, using the link I made, but bear in mind the div containers will output as blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because HTML is only meant to give semantic meaning for your text. While browsers do give some default styling to most elements, that is merely a suggestion and default styling can vary from browser to browser. So as far as HTML goes, if they would try to implement a `<triangle>` tag it would go absolutely against all best practices. And they did have tags that defined style at the beginning of WEB (,  etc etc..). But it has proven to be a nightmare to maintain. Therefore the styling element of WEB was delegated to CSS.

Now as far as CSS goes, it has come a long way since the begining. So while there is no easy way to do it but most of the stuff you mention can be achieved with CSS.. stuff like circles is actually quite easy. When it comes to triangles it is bit more difficult. But these days prity much anything can be done with a bit of CSS and JavaScript magic. There is plenty of Javascript libraries that specialise in drawing/animating stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That's not HTML's purpose, which is for marking up documents. They invented things like SVG to do that, and extensible markup languages like XHTML that you can slot them right into in a modular way.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before HTML and CSS do not include any serious shape functionality.
The closest thing without the use of a script like Javascript and Canvas would be SVG, which is in fact just a vector graphic written in XML.

Further informations on SVG:

1. http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp
2. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/